Why there is steady DC current in a metal under static $E$ field in the presence of Bloch oscillation?
Background: This is a question regarding the Bloch oscillation and the solid state description of shifted Fermi sphere under static electric field.
Question:
One explanation for a steady current formation under $E$ field is due to a shift in Fermi-sphere: in equilibrium, there are same number of carriers of velocity $v$ and $-v$, and therefore the net current is zero; when the static field $\vec{E}$ is turned on, the Fermi sphere shifts along the field direction and an imbalance of forward and backward propagating carrier density is created.

However, we know this shifted Fermi sphere should not be static----there will be Bloch oscillation taking place. This shifted Fermi sphere should periodically oscillate inside the Brillouin zone. Therefore, in a perfect crystal we should not see DC current under static field at all, but an AC current.
So what is the reason we see a DC current in real metal? Is it due to a momentum-dependent scattering mechanism, i.e. forward scattering is more likely than back scattering?

"However, we know this shifted Fermi sphere should not be static... This shifted Fermi sphere should periodically oscillate." No, we do not know this. First, the field could be turned on slowly compared to other time scales. In this case there is no reason to suspect any oscillatory behavior. Second, a real material will exhibit damping and oscillations can die out. Certainly if you hit the metal with a quick pulse you can see oscillations, but your picture is just showing what appears to be a constant/static uniform field...

I guess maybe this is what you are asking about? But it's not so clear. Seems like you are making two contradictory statements. But maybe you are just asking about damping?

@hft no, under crystalline physics the question as OP asked is correct. The OP is just forgetting that the deviation of the Fermi surface from the equilibrium position is itself unstable, and other processes exist. In particular, umklapp scattering, phonon scattering and impurity scattering would serve to restore the equilibrium distribution. Because of that, the Fermi surface would not be running around the BZ, and instead would just settle down in a steady state displacement from equilibrium, and it is that on-average-constant displacement that is what we actually measure.

@naturallyInconsistent Thank you, your explanation basically answers my question. To make sure I understand you correctly, let me rephrase your answer: If without any scattering, the Fermi surface under a static field would travel periodically inside Brillouin zone and perform Bloch oscillation as a whole. However, since in reality there is different scattering mechanism such as umklapp scattering, phonon scattering and impurity scattering, these "restoring" effect will balance the effect of a static E field and leads to a static shift of Fermi surface. Is this correct? Thank you.

Yes. It is not clear what is the appropriate zero-scattering limit because the result is so ridiculous, but at least we are in agreement that with scattering, the net effect is of a steady state net displacement without oscillations, with the theoretically predicted net effect in agreement with experiment.
